# Can we build a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n \to x$ and $f(x_n) \to \liminf _{y \to x} f(y)$?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

I'm reading [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Characterization_of_Lower_Semicontinuity) proof about closed level sets implying l.s.c. The essential part of the proof is the existence of below sequence $(x_n)$.

> Let $S$ be a topological space and $f:S \to \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$. For $x \in S$, let $\mathcal N(x)$ be the set of all open neighborhoods $V$ of $x$. Let $$a := \liminf _{y \to x} f(y) := \sup _{V \in \mathcal N (x)} \inf _{y \in V \setminus \{x\}} f(y).$$

Can we build a sequence $(x_n)$ in $S$ such that $x_n \to x$ and $f(x_n) \to a$? In my rudimentary attempt, I can not guarantee that $x_n \to x$.

---

Let $\lambda_n := a - 1/(n+1)$. Then there is a sequence $(V_n)$ of neighborhoods of $x$ such that $$\lambda_n < \alpha_n :=\inf_{y \in V_n \setminus \{x\}} f(y) \le \lambda, \quad n \in \mathbb N.$$

By axiom of choice, there is a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $$x_n \in V_n \setminus \{x\} \text{ and } \alpha_n \le f(x_n) < \beta_n := \alpha_n + 1/(n+1), \quad n \in \mathbb N.$$

---

**Update:** I added the proof in the link for convenience.

Let all lower level sets of $f$ be closed. Let $x \in S$ and $a := \liminf _{y \rightarrow x} f(y)$. In order to prove that $f$ is LSC it suffices to show that $a = f(x)$. We know already that $a \leq f(x)$. Thus it suffices to show that $f(x) \leq a$.

Let $a=\infty$. As $\infty \leq \infty$ the proof is complete. Let $a<\infty$. Then we can find a sequence $\left\langle x_{n}\right\rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that:
$$
x_{n} \rightarrow x \text { and } f\left(x_{n}\right) \rightarrow a
$$

For any $b>a$ , we have $f\left(x_{n}\right) \leq b$ or equivalently $x_{n} \in \operatorname{lev}_{\leq b} f$ which by hypothesis is closed. Therefore $\operatorname{lev}_{\leq b} f$ contains the limit point $x$. We have that for all $b>a$, $f(x) \leq b$. Therefore, $f(x) \leq a$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. You'd need $X$ to be a sequential space for this argument to go through. I think you can argue analogously with nets, however.

Comment: @TheoBendit I have added the proof given in https://proofwiki.org/. According to your comment, the proof is not correct. Could you have a look and confirm it?